# In C#, do objects which have a local scope use the stack?

Tags: c#, stack

Say we have

```
void Foo() {
    var bar = new Bar();
    bar.Woo();
}
```

Will the CLR use the stack for the local variable?

If not, why? Is it not more efficient to use the stack for variables which have a limited scope instead of using a more expensive garbage collector?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793808/how-are-arrays-created-and-accessed/7796686#7796686) from Eric Lippert on a different question and read the entire comments. This sort of question comes up often. At any rate, the newly created `Bar` will go on the heap.

Comment: The second part of his question is not really a duplicate. The answer to his first question is no, the variable will be allocated on the heap. This leads us to the second question.

Comment: I would also recommend Eric's blog series "The Stack is an Implementation Detail" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the CLR would need to know that the scope is local, but also that the object wont be referenced from anywhere else. This would need a deep code analysis except for the most trivial cases, like the one you posted.

Comment: Even in the example posted, bar.Woo() could easily cause bar to be referenced elsewhere

Comment: @jeffora I hadn't considered that Bar.Woo() could assign some longer scoped variable to `this`. I understand now why we can't just put those objects on the stack. My appreciation on C# and its design just went up another notch.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, some type of [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) could be performed by the CLR. If that led to the conclusion that the object was *only* accessible from the local context, it could then go ahead and allocate the object on the stack. At this point, however, that is not done, and a class will always be allocated in the long-term storage area (aka "the heap".)

Also, note that the *variable* `bar` *is* allocated on the stack (or possibly enregistered). It contains a reference to the newly created `Bar` object (on the heap), and will disappear when the method exits.

Answer (score 0):

the Value Type is on stack 
and for Reference type the reference(the things like pointer) is on stack but the object is on managed heap

refer to 
C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types
http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Comment: That's inaccurate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113819/c-arrays-heap-and-stack-and-value-types

Comment: Your statement about value types is greatly over-simplified and is often wrong. Think of it this way. `class C { int i; }` Where does `int i` live? Obviously, with the instance of C. Where does the instance of C live?